# Resize popup Window to min. height and width then dragging to below size should not possible

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

i want to fix my popup windows size to minimum height of 400 and width of 650, after that even dragging to below that size should not be possible, i used resizeTo() function, but still dragging is possible, i want to lock my popup window  after that mini. size, and more than that height and width , window should be resize. any one have answer using javascript???
Here is what i done::>>

var newHeight = $(window).height();
            var newWidth = $(window).width();

```
        /*newWidth < 650 ? window.innerWidth = 650 : $(window).height();
        newHeight < 400 ? window.innerHeight = 400 : $(window).width()*/;

        if (newWidth < 633) 
            {
               window.resizeTo(650,newHeight+72);
            }

        else if (newHeight < 327) {
                window.resizeTo(newWidth,400);
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use from JQUERY UI resizeable function. Once check with that it will very easy method for this task. all the best

Comment: hey thankx bt, That is not helpful for window resizing.... still window is resizing below that size btwn thanx for commentingso , i learnt one more new thing

Comment: you want to change your popup window size, if you like this method then you can make css div same like popup and then apply this if you want. It is also a solution for your problem and with this method you can also add another js/jquery functionality. which is not possible with window popup's.